# UI scaling for WXGA resolution

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8.1

currently I'm having a few difficulties with the UI of a Windows Phone app. I've always thought that the UI is automatically scaled by the OS to fit the resolution of the device properly. In the designer of Visual Studio or Blend the UI of my app looks pretty much the same for all different device types/resolutions I can select in the preview. When I debug the app on the WVGA, the 720p emulator and my device (Lumia 920), it does look the same, too. But when I start the app in the WXGA emulator the UI looks as it is not scaled by the OS. It only fills the first half of the screen and everything is very tiny.

Now I am very confused: Why does the UI scaling work for many resolutions but WXGA, and why does the preview in the designer look totally different in comparison to the result in the emulator.

Doing researches I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-57-37-metablogapi/7624.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_2064885E.png) image to explain the different resolutions for Windows Phone. If I'm understanding it correctly the UI should look almost the same of all different resolutions as it should be scaled.
Now I need to know why it's not scaled under WXGA resolution or what else I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: As I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 I cannot edit anything resolution dependend in the `WMAppManifest.xml` as this was mentioned in some other posts I found.

Is it possible, that my emulator is the problem and not the app itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be the emulator's problem because Lumia 920 has WXGA resolution. Recreating WXGA virtual machine may help your case.

Comment: @David To How can I recreate it? By reinstalling the Devloper SDK? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Open Hyper-V Manager program, you can see the list of current VMs.

Comment: @DavidTo Deleting the virtual machine and letting it be restored by VS did not help - the problem is still existent. I'll now try to reinstall the WP8.1 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

you can find your answer for  Adapting UI for Different Screens and Orientations

visit http://www.slideshare.net/WindowsPhoneRocks/06-adapting-ui-for-different-screens-and-orientations . I have used scaled 120 and it works fine in both WVGA and  WXGA

refer http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/06

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have done nasty things in your app (I'm not even sure it's possible, probably not), 
I think this is an emulator related problem in your SDK installation.
Which version of the emulators are you using (WP8, WP8 Update3, WP8.1)?

If you have installed more than one emulators set, i.e. wp8 and wp8.1, try the WXGA in more than one set and see if they are different.